# Store email credential in web.config file

Tags: c#, smtp

I am trying to store email credential from `Startup.cs` file to `web.config` file.

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appSettings"];
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("service@gmail.com", "123456");
mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
mySmtpClient.Port = 587;

MailAddress from = new MailAddress("service@gmail.com", "ActiveDirectoryInformation");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com");
//MailAddress to = new MailAddress("it@sarajevoosiguranje.ba");
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

myMail.Subject = "ActiveDirectory";
myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

// set body-message and encoding
myMail.Body = @"Ukupno novih korisnika:" + noviKorisnika + "<br>" +
              @"Ukupno izmjenjenih korisnika: " + izmjenjenihKorisnika;
myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
// text or html
myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

And I create in my `app.config` file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="smtpServer" value="smtp.net" />
    <add key="Username" value="service@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="Password" value="test123456abc"/>
    <add key="EnableSsl" value = "true"/>
    <add key="smtpPort" value="587" />
    <add key="from" value="service@gmail.com" />
    <add key="to" value ="test@gmail.com"></add>    
</appSettings>
```

The reason why I do that is that I want to publish this application live, and maybe in future when I change `sender` or `receiver` email address I don't want to compile application again and publish it.

It is easy way to store everything in app.config and read from there.

Any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have understood, you want to store information in App.config file which is pretty easy.

## Step 1

Add System.Configuration.dll reference to your project if you don't have it already.

Project > myAwsomeProject > References > Add Reference > Find System.Configuration.dll

(or something like that) and add it to your project.

## Step 2

import the System.Configuration.dll using:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then create a function or write the code in the third step under your main();

## Step 3

Create an instance of the Configuration class that refers to your App.config file

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

## Step 4

Use the following syntax to read from your App.config file

```
config.AppSettings.Settings["mykey"].Value
```

in which you would replace the "mykey" value with the corresponding key name. For example in your case Username or Password

## Step 5

Use the following syntax to write to/change value of a key

```
config.AppSettings.Settings["mykey"].Value = "value";
```

"mykey" is the key and "value" is the desired value

#### Do NOT forget to save the configuration file after you write to it or after all the operations are done!!!

```
config.Save();
```

## Step 6 (Optional)

You can also add and remove keys to your App.Config file

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("newKey", "value");         
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("mykey");
```

Again after each operation concerning the modification of the file. Save the file

```
config.Save();
```

## Important Note

The app.config file is not the one you see in your solution explorer in visual studio. The one in the solution explorer will not be modified even after it is saved.

The app.config that you will be using and modifying will be located in
  C:\Users\yourUsername\source\repos\yourAwsomeProject\yourAwsomeProject\bin\Debug

or if it is in release mode
    C:\Users\yourUsername\source\repos\yourAwsomeProject\yourAwsomeProject\bin\Release

or if you are using a custom project path

```
\Path\To\your\Awsome\Project\yourAwsomeProject\bin\Release
```

and the file will be named as

```
yourAwsomeProject.exe.config
```

(Correct me if I am wrong or misunderstood the question)

Comment: You are right ! This is what I am looking for 
Thank you

Comment: I think you made mistake about App.config file When I opet path 
`C:\Users\yourUsername\source\repos\yourAwsomeProject\yourAwsomeProject\bin\Debug` I see that application containt  ADApp.exe.config file alredy

Comment: Yes, I meant that the file is not modified in the visual studio but you can see the modifications if you open the file at that path

Comment: You mean, I can open but if I change something inside there `VS` will not affect this changes. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes If you change something in the application and save it. The app.config file in the visual studio will stay the same. The yourapp.exe.config file in your yourApp\debug will be modified and changed and saved. The file in the VS is kind of a template that the yourapp.exe.config will be created from.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Sorry one more question, I didnt get this step here
config.AppSettings.Settings["mykey"].Value = "value";
What I need to pass to `value`

Comment: Information is stored as key-value pairs in the app.config file. if key "username" value can be "myAwsomeUsername4477" or whatever you want to store as the username.

Comment: I dont want to display key value inside this. I only want to store email and pass in app.config file and from my Main.cs read what is inside app.config. I resolve problem bro. 
I test it, and It works :)

Comment: @unknow_user Did you understand what that meant? If you didn't, try running the code and in your app.exe.config file that is created, you will see that the value part near the key will be "value" like ```<add key="mykey" value="value" />```

Comment: Yes, I understand what does it mean. But I dont want to display this in my code. Because in future If I change sender or reciver address I also need to modify in my code, but I dont want this. I want only read what is inside `app.config` file

Comment: @unknow_user If you only want to read Step 4 will be adequate. If you wanted to change the username or password programmatically you could use Step 5. Steps are just to teach you the basics of app settings. They are not specific to the question.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thank you :)

Comment: Again, no problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you or not but I was able to store SMTP information inside the app.config file for one of my old C# applications.

However, the To: address was not stored as part of the credentials so I stored those information in a local SQLite file.

To retrieve the settings you just need to initialize a `SmtpClient` object which will read from the local config file.

Hope this helps.

```
        public static void WriteDefaultSMTPSettingsToConfigurationFile()
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettingsSectionGroup = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

            SmtpSection smtpSection = mailSettingsSectionGroup.Smtp;

            if (!smtpSection.ElementInformation.IsPresent)
            {
                smtpSection.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
                smtpSection.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

                SmtpNetworkElement smtpNetworkElement = smtpSection.Network;
                smtpNetworkElement.Host = "localhost";
                smtpNetworkElement.Port = 465;
                smtpNetworkElement.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpNetworkElement.UserName = "username";
                smtpNetworkElement.Password = "password";

                config.Save();
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.net/mailSettings");
            }
        }
```